# loading html into another html with javascript (without external files)

Tags: javascript, html, import

I have a  code which I used to load external files into a html. How can I do it without importing external files or any libraries, so inside html I can type a short script and it will load another page?
i use this script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#outer').load('html_file.html');
});
```

but it requires to have additional files + libraries. How can I do everything directly in html?

Any ideas?

basically I want to include the whole another website inside the new one, but I can use only html + javascript inside the html file. All css files will be stored and reffered in the imported file.

Comment: is it ajax? or jquery? and wat have u tried?

Comment: If you want to include the whole other website, can you not just use an iFrame?

Comment: You are already using jQuery in your code. That should be enough. Download jQuery from here http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js

Comment: Well, how about `$('#outer').load('http://www.yoursite.com');` ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you looking to use jQuery without having to import the jQuery library?  No, browsers don't have jQuery built-in.  You can write the functionality you need manually.  Or I guess copy/paste the jQuery library into a `script` tag in your page.  But I don't see a reason for that.  Why not just use what you're already using?

Comment: thanks for '-'. whatever it is for. I am not an expert and I'm playing with this for around 1 hour... no results so I posted my question here. thanks for understanding my problem.... anyway, regarding further questions - I can use iframe, but this is for mobile devices and Im not sure will this always work. will it? also i need to specify the height of iframe, and it can change in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this "html":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open("GET", "html_file.html", false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
};
</script>
```

Comment: @Esailija Well well well, good ol' `XMLHttpRequest` is back in town. Haven't seen since `$.ajax` :)

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski please see if there are any errors. Have you also used my latest edit? My initial code was wrong. It is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/VfeaA/

Comment: sorry, i cant vote yet, too small reputation. but you deserved a massive vote up! thanks

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski you can accept the answer. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for instructions. You just click the white checkmark below the vote buttons.